# How to use ZAP to automate active scan during HTTP Post?

Tags: security, zap

is there any best practice to use ZAP to do the active scan ?

for example... we want to active scan a login page, to input some injection code to see if the login function would be injected or not..

And we hope to implement the whole scan in script with zapv2 library, is there any best practice to do like that ?

Currently, we could use zapv2 script to passive scan the site nicely, but still have no idea about how to use ZAP/zapV2 to automate active scan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The github repo has examples: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-api-python/tree/master/src/examples

There's a decent write-up here: https://www.coveros.com/scripting-owasp-zap/
The zaproxy wiki has details too: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/ApiPython
etc.

Here's an example of running an active scan via the python API (assuming you've already spidered or proxied some unit tests or something to build up the sites tree, and that `target` is defined):

```
print ('Active Scanning target {}'.format(target))
scanid = zap.ascan.scan(target)
while (int(zap.ascan.status(scanid)) < 100):
    # Loop until the scanner has finished
    print ('Scan progress %: {}'.format(zap.ascan.status(scanid)))
    time.sleep(5)

print ('Active Scan completed')
```

Of course you could also just hit up google or duckduckgo or whatever your favorite search engine is and try something like "zaproxy python examples".